# Is it true that cursive "stimulate" brain better than other types of handwriting?

Tags: iq, brain-training, writing

Is it true that cursive "stimulate" brain better than other types of handwriting?
I find lots of [links](https://thinkwrite-learning.co.uk/article_detail.php?title=part1-the-neurological-benefits-of-cursive-writing) about this topic,  but has it been scientifically proven?

Comment: This question would benefit from greater clarity. Are you interested in whether there are studies on whether certain types of handwriting improve learning? I doubt cursive would make any difference but comparing handwriting to laptops there may be some benefit (see http://www.danielwillingham.com/daniel-willingham-science-and-education-blog/new-studies-show-the-cost-of-student-laptop-use-in-college-lectures)

Comment: @MalcolmForbes yes

Comment: Not aware of any studies. I assume that any positive effect, if it existed, would be so marginal to render it meaningless. You also need to consider the opportunity cost associated with the time to learn cursive.